# Add a sudomain for each folder in my userdir path with Apache

Tags: apache, subdomain, mod-userdir

I activated the userdir mod with apache2 and configure my domain to get the content of the `www` folder in my home.
I create a Virtualhost for the main domain which works good.
But now i would like to automatically add a subdomain for each folder in my `/home/user/www/`

Here is the virtualhost i code, but it redirect all the subdomains to the `/home/user/www/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias *.mysite.com

DocumentRoot /home/user/www/

UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /home/user/www/%1

<Directory /home/user/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.mysite.log
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2.mysite.log combined
</VirtualHost>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /home/user/www/%1
```

to:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /home/user/www/%0
```

You can read more about this feature at [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#interpol).

Comment: I need to add a VirtualHost for each subdomain ?

Comment: Not really. I missed the `VirtualDocumentRoot` feature, sorry.

Comment: Yeah :) But i read in the docs `mod_vhost_alias` is overwrite by `mod_user` wich i use too. Do you know more about this ?

Comment: Nope... I've never used `mod_userdir`. Having them both enabled seems a bit crazy, though.